# Convergence in inner product space

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $X$ be an inner product space. If $x_n\to x$, $y_n\to y$ (in norm), then $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$ (in modulus).

Comment: what is: "in modulus"?

Comment: I assume the modulus of $(x, y)$ is $\sqrt{||x||^2 + ||y||^2}$, where $||\cdot ||$ is the norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add and subtract $(x,y_n)$ and use Cauchy's and triangle inequality many times.

$$\begin{align}|(x,y)-(x_n,y_n)|&=|(x,y)-(x,y_n)+(x,y_n)-(x_n,y_n)|\\&\leq |(x,y-y_n)|+|(x-x_n,y_n)|\\&\leq ||x||\cdot||y-y_n||+||x-x_n||\cdot||y_n||\\&\leq||x||\cdot||y-y_n||+||x-x_n||\cdot(||y||+\epsilon)\end{align}$$

for $n$ large such that $||y_n||-||y||\leq ||y_n-y||<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "modulus" but other definition of the norm on $X \times Y$ could probably be done with very similar proofs.

Let $\|\cdot\|_X,\|\cdot\|_Y$ be norms on $X$ and $Y$ and $\|\cdot\|_{X\times Y}:X \times Y \to \Bbb R: (u,v)\mapsto \sqrt{\|u\|_X^2+\|v\|^2_2}$. Let us suppose that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} \subset X$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} \subset Y$ are sequences so that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n-x\|_X =0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\|y_n-y\|_Y =0.$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N_1,N_2>0$ such that $$\|x_n-x\|_X < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}\qquad \forall n > N_1$$ and $$\|y_n-y\|_Y < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}\qquad \forall n > N_2.$$ Then for every $n > \max\{N_1,N_2\}$ we get
$$\|(x_n,y_n)-(x,y)\|_{X\times Y}= \sqrt{\|x-x_n\|_X^2+\|y_n-y\|^{{{2}}}_2}\leq \sqrt{\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2} = \epsilon.$$
That is $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ in the norm $\|\cdot\|_{X \times Y}$

Comment: Hi, would the inverse of the claim hold? i.e. if $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ in $||.||_{X\times Y}$ in product space, then $x_n\to x$ in $||.||_X$ and $y_n \to y$ in $||.||_Y$?

Comment: @user91360 yes, because the embedding $\pi_X\colon X\times Y \to X$ with $\pi_X(x,y)=x$ is continuous (if you consider the product topology on $X\times Y$). Same same for $\pi_Y(x,y)=y$.