# Continuous mapping theorem for infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Assume that we are given two random sequences, defined on the same probability spaces and taking values from $\ell_{2}$. Next, assume that $X_{n}\overset{a.s.}{\to} a$ and $Y_{n}\overset{a.s.}{\to} b$.

Next, let's takes some continuous function $f: \ell_{2} \times \ell_{2} \to \mathbb{R}$. Can we now apply continuous mapping theorem to prove that
$$
f(X_{n}, Y_{n}) \overset{a.s.}{\to} f(a,b)?
$$

**Attempt:** if $f$ is just the inner product, then the result it correct, see, for example
[Convergence in inner product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096453/convergence-in-inner-product-space).

Also, here [Functional continuous mapping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018088/functional-continuous-mapping-theorem?rq=1) is the example where one must be careful with continuous mapping theorem.

Comment: Your notion of convergence means that for almost all $\omega$ in the probability space you want $X_n(\omega)\to a$ where $a\in \ell_2$?

Comment: yes, the standard meaning on a.s. convergence in Probability theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of $\omega$ for which either $X_n(\omega)$ or $Y_n(\omega)$ doesn't converge is a null set, as it is a union of two null sets.

So for almost all $\omega$ you have $(X_n(\omega), Y_n(\omega))\to (a,b)$. By continuity of $f$ you then get that for such $\omega$ $f(X_n(\omega),Y_n(\omega))\to f(a,b)$ - hence $f(X_n, Y_n)$ converges almost surely to $f(a,b)$.

Comment: this is the thing: I did not say that $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ converge together as random element element of product space $\ell_{2} \times \ell_{2}$. Though, both $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are defined on the same probability space.

Comment: @LrM: It should be easy to show that if $X_n \to a$ a.s. and $Y_n \to b$ a.s, then $(X_n, Y_n) \to (a,b)$ in the product topology a.s.

Comment: @LrM the set of $\omega$ for which $X_n(\omega)$ doesn't converge to $a$ is a null set. The set of $\omega$ for which $Y_n(\omega)$ doesn't converge to $b$ is a null set. The union of those two sets is then a null set - and the union is precisely the set of points $\omega$ for which $(X_n(\omega) , Y_{n}(\omega))$ doesn't converge to $(a,b)$.